# VSCode Extension for auditing solidity code

Tags: solidity, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I work as an auditor in the DeFi space, which means I get to dive into other people's code quite a lot in my everyday work.
I usually get to read several contracts in each project i'm working on, some of them are really long and complex pieces of code.

As I do these auditing jobs for systems that work mainly on ethereum, i get to read a lot of solidity code. I use VScode for browsing and reading through the libraries i get to audit, and so i use 2 solidity extensions to make my life easier:

- [tintinweb's Solidity Visual Developer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintinweb.solidity-visual-auditor)
- [Juan Blanco's](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity)

Im not sure how, but somehow both are enabled without creating any conflict any im happy for that. The 1st one is nice since it displays some additional data as sighash of functions, relate to unit tests, show dependencies, etc. However it has poor support for go to definition feature. The 2nd extension does a slightly better job with go to definition, but still pretty frequently does not jump 2 lines up to the definition of functions and  within the same contract (not to mention functions defined in other contracts).

Can you think of an extension(s) that may be useful to me as an auditor? specifically a good go to definition feature is life changing in this job, but also things like showing var type, access to sighash, jump to unit tests, etc., which already exist in extension #1 are important.

No wrong answers here, to each his own, i'd just like to try out as many (recommended) etensions as possible and decide for myself.

Thanks :>

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackExchange. It's great that you added details, but StackExchange is tailored to specific questions that can be answered succinctly (or practically). This question would likely trigger opinionated answers, which is why I am voting to close it. Beside that, there are actually multiple questions wrapped in one - it's better to make a new post for each question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I recommend taking a look at [Hardhat VSCode](https://medium.com/nomic-labs-blog/hardhat-vscode-9de29467fc26) (if you happen to be a Hardhat user).

Comment: Mocha Test Explorer is quite fun: https://hardhat.org/guides/vscode-tests.html - is hardhat vscode already out?

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth you can ask for access to the beta.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers, will have a look at your suggestions.
additional suggestions will be appreciated.
@PaulRazvanBerg I see what you mean, but I think it's a valid question that can be useful for others in the future. Opinions are fine to have, and i dont believe any harm will be caused due to this question. i suggest we'll leave it open, and close it if it becomes irrelevant (people are arguing, etc.)
If i need to reduce it to 1 question i would ask what extension is recommended for my purposes.

Comment: Please modify your question accordingly (ie the edit you're suggesting). Feel free to read  "What kind of question should I avoid asking" from the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask (I'm mostly using tintin's web one, but that's an opinion, not a valid SE answer...)